# Cannot include Prometheus metrics in spring boot 2 (version 2.0.0.M7)

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, prometheus

Cannot include Prometheus metrics in spring boot 2 (version 2.0.0.M7) project.

According [micrometer docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/2.0#_prometheus) added **spring-boot-starter-actuator** dependency and in application.yaml added **management.endpoints.web.expose: prometheus** but when calling */actuator/prometheus* get
`{
    "timestamp": 1518159066052,
    "path": "/actuator/prometheus",
    "message": "Response status 404 with reason \"No matching handler\"",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found"
}`

Tell me please why I wasn't getting prometheus metrics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add `micrometer-registry-prometheus` to your dependecies?

Micrometer has a pluggable architecture where you need to define (by plugging dependencies) what monitoring system you'd like to work with. (You can even add multiple, not just one.)

Btw, you should be switching to Spring Boot `2.0.0.RC1`. That's the current one as of this writing.

Comment: yes, I added `micrometer-registry-prometheus` dependency, but it didn't solve my issue. In documentation found `endpoints.prometheus.id: micrometheus`, but in application.yaml I wasn't getting it.

Comment: @makson What "web" technology are you using? When I test with `spring-boot-starter-web` it works with `2.0.0.M7` and also with `2.0.0.RC1`. But when I test with `spring-boot-starter-jersey` a 404 is spit out. The actuator endpoints aren't registered.
You need to add/register a `ResourceConfig` Bean to your context in order for the `JerseyAutoConfiguration` to kick in.

Comment: I am using `RouterFunctions` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. After update spring to `2.0.0.RC1` all work. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I had trouble initiating micrometer with Springboot 2. x.

These changes in my project helped me to expose the metrics at`actuator/prometheus`  endpoint

These are the changes in my **application.properties** file

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
```

My **build.gradle** file included

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus')
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Spring boot 2.7.3. Year 2023.

Answer (score 10):

*Edit: Since I gave this answer a lot has changed. It was valid for 2.0.0.RC1. Please read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html*

If above solution doesn't work for someone try this:
I had the same issue with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1, spring-boot-starter-web and of course spring-boot-starter-actuator.

My application.properties file read:

```
management.endpoints.web.expose=prometheus,metrics,info,health
```

In my pom file I had additionally:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Prometheus metrics under /actuator/prometheus where only shown after I had switched to the newest version of micrometer-registry-prometheus:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-rc.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I think the property `management.endpoints.web.expose` should instead be `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE, shouldn't it?

And in the meantime there has also been a release of `micrometer-registry-prometheus`, at the time of writing it's `1.0.1`.

Comment: DerMiggel - I think you're right. @cholland can you amend your answer? I had a false-start with it.

Answer (score 0):

Recap:

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </parent>

... ... ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties.yml (aka. application.yml)**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,prometheus
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.show-components=always
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.metrics.tags.application=TheApplicationName
```

---

After applying all the above, **health & info** endpoints were displayed in the http://localhost:8080/actuator -list, but not the prometheus endpoint.

Of course, rerun the Maven lifecycle - still failing prometheus to be displayed ...

---

Finally my issue disappeared after **invalidate caches and restart** of my **IntelliJ IDE**