# /actuator/prometheus is not exposed

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I use spring-boot 2.0.0 and tried to expose /actuator/prometheus endpoint.
I enabled all of web management endpoints, but only prometheus endpoint was not exposed. any helps?

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

```
2018-03-04 03:11:07.854  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/auditevents],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.854  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/beans],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.854  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.855  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/conditions],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.855  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/configprops],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.855  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/env],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.855  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/env/{toMatch}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.855  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.855  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.856  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers/{name}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.856  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/loggers/{name}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.856  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/heapdump],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.857  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/threaddump],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.857  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.857  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/metrics],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.857  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/scheduledtasks],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.857  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/httptrace],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.858  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/mappings],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-03-04 03:11:07.858  INFO 7864 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: Die you add the necessary dependency? Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706233/9071502

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the wildcard but using this in the application.yml works.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus
```